# Why Travel Time is not available for all calendars?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, exchange, caldav

I have two calendars set on my iPhone : one with CalDAV and another one with Exchange.

When I create an appointment in my CalDAV calendar, the « Travel Time » field is available, and I can select an address in the « Location field » :

[image: Travel time with CalDAV]
[image: Location with CalDAV]

But when I create an appointment in my Exchange calendar, the « Travel Time » field disappeared and I am unable to set a location.

[image: Travel Time with Exchange]
[image: Location with Exchange]

Any idea of why Travel Time and Location are not available for all types of calendar ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the server has been configured for.  Travel Time is not something that is configured (normally) or by default in an Exchange Server.  Same thing for the Location field, however, by Default it's on.  On my particular Exchange server (hosted by MS365), Location is available by default.

Check with the admin of the Exchange server as to why those features aren't available.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that it is one of those things that Apple's calendar does not support out of the box. And considering that MS does not either...

The (free) MS Outlook client has a location option but the "travel time" option is not available just that location field for the Calendar Event.

From what I can find MS does not provide that feature out of the box in *anything*.

There might be a 3rd party add-on that does this but I am not aware of one.